# c# getting array element number

Tags: c#, arrays, numbers, max

I currently have two arrays one the stores a file name and another that stores the file size. I need to show both the maximum file size and its name. I can get it to show the largest file by using this code.

```
        long[] fileSize;
        string[] fileName;
        fileSize = new long[fileCount];
        fileName = new string[fileCount];
        for (int index = 0; index < files.Length; index++)
        {
            fileSize[index] = files[index].Length;
            fileName[index] = files[index].Name;
        }
        long largestFile = fileSize.Max();
        string latestFileName = fileName[fileSize.Max()];
        Console.WriteLine("Total size of all files: {0}", totalSize);
        Console.WriteLine("Largest file: {1}, {0}", largestFile, latestFileName );
```

I have tried using google but it just tells me how to work out the maximum or minimum.

Comment: Are the requirements that you have to use arrays?

Comment: Do you need to use an array? There are plenty of native .NET collection objects that store name-value pairs that you could use. Or for maximum flexibility, there's always a System.Data.Datatable object. the name of the file and the size, as well as other attributes, could be kept in the same row and eliminate this unnecessary complexity.

Comment: there are no requirements of what I have to use, I just have to show the largest file's size and name.

Comment: Is there question any where ?

Comment: Then as all the other comments mention, use a Dictionary<string, long> the key would be your filename

Comment: @SurjitSamra Yes, it's at the top of this page ;)

Comment: thanks David I am going to have a look at using System.Data.Datatable

Comment: thanks for all the responses think I can get it working now

Comment: Bear in mind that, in the general case, its possible for multiple files to be the "largest".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for separate arrays for the name and size, just loop over your `files` array, and keep track of the current max file size and it's name in separate variables. Something like this:

```
int max = 0;
string name = string.Empty;

for (int index = 0; index < files.Length; index++)
{
    int size = files[index].Length;
    //check if this file is the biggest we've seen so far
    if (size > max)
    {
        max = size; //store the size
        name = files[index].Name; //store the name
    }
}

//here, "name" will be the largest file name, and "max" will be the largest file size.
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider using Dictionary instead of arrays. Arrays might get out of sync and it's harder to manage

```
        var info = new Dictionary<string, long>();
        info.Add("test.cs", 24);
        var maxSize = info.Values.Max();
        Console.WriteLine(info.Single(p => p.Value == maxSize).Key);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        var largestFiles = files.Where((f1) => f1.Length == files.Max((f2) => f2.Length));

        // it's possible that there are multiple files that are the same size and are also the largest files.
        foreach (var file in largestFiles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", file.Name, file.Length);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Max` returns the maximum *value*, not the maximum value's *index*, that's why your index lookup does not work. You may try this:

```
long largestSize = -1;
int largest = -1;
for (int index = 0; index < files.Length; index++)
{
    fileSize[index] = files[index].Length;
    fileName[index] = files[index].Name;

    if(fileSize[index] > largestSize)
    {
        largestSize = fileSize[index];
        largest = index;
    }
}
```

Or, as others pointed out, use an array of `Tuple<string, long>`, a `Dictionary<string, int>` (if file names are unique), or even the file types you had before.